# Excluding Thorntail dependencies does not work, leading to WELD-001408

Tags: maven, jboss-weld, thorntail

I have a Thorntail-based project A, which uses the Thorntail bom-all and a number of Thorntail dependencies:

pom.xml

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
                <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ...
```

Everything there works fine in project A.

---

I want to use some classes of project A in project B. For that I've configured the maven-war-plugin in project A like this, in other to create a classes-jar:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${version.maven-war-plugin}</version>
   <configuration>
      <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My project B has a very similar setup to project A, using the same Thorntail version and also the Thorntail bom-all and a number of Thorntail dependencies. In order to use the classes from project A, I've added it to the pom.xml in project B:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>my.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>project.a</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

---

However, when I want to run the Thorntail uberjar of project B, I get the typical WELD-001408 exception with the issue always being some class of a Thorntail dependency:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Archive with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor(Archive)
  at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.<init>(DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.java:0)
```

In the pom.xml of project B, I've tried to exclude the Thorntail dependencies (separately and also using * for the artifactId) from the project A dependency using the exclusions element, but I still get the same errors at the Thorntail startup.

---

Does someone have an idea how to deal with this? Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: This is strange. Can you look into the `classes` artifact, if it perhaps contains some Thorntail classes (or other remnants of Thorntail)?

Comment: @Ladicek thanks for your reply. I've already checked this and just did again: The only trace of Thorntail in the classes.jar is in the pom (_classes.jar\META-INF\maven\my.group\project.a\pom.xml_). Everything else is just my project's classes and resources.
Do you have any other idea, where I could be looking for the cause of this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, not at the moment. Can you possibly put a small reproducer on GitHub? Thanks!

Comment: @Ladicek I've created a minimal reproducer: https://github.com/flo-ryan/thorntail-test
Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: OK, now I know what's happening. Some Thorntail JARs end up inside `WEB-INF/lib` in the repackaged `test2.war`, because the `test1` module dependens on them. You have added exclusions, which is correct in principle, but the Thorntail Maven plugin unfortunately doesn't honor dependency exclusions when repackaging the WAR (it needs to figure out which JARs to keep in `WEB-INF/lib` and which to remove). This is fixed in the master branch and should be fixed in Thorntail 2.7.0, which should be released roughly in 5 or 6 weeks.

Comment: @Ladicek thanks for your analysis! Then I'll just wait for the next release. Could you maybe send me the link to the issue, if you have it at hand? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly when it was fixed, because this was a known behavior for quite a while and there was no specific effort to fix this particular problem. However, a couple of related issues were fixed recently, so I checked if perhaps this issue is also fixed, and it is. If you want to work around it in the meantime, you can have your `test1` module depend only on Java EE specification JARs in `<scope>provided</scope>`, and either rely on fraction autodetection, or use the `<fractions>` configuration element of the `thorntail-maven-plugin`.

Comment: @Ladicek ah okay - so you simply checked that the issue was fixed with the current working branch for the next release. Thank you very much!